# IIS 8 Two Applications in One Site - Response.Redirect("~/")

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I'm quite the novice with IIS, and am trying to setup two applications in one website. This is what I have done:

I have created a website in IIS, and have added two applications to the website. I can successfully navigate to:

```
http://servername/site1
http://servername/site2
```

Each of my different applications show up, and everything appears to work fine. The issue is what the redirects in my C# code actually redirect to. I try to navigate to a different page like the following:

```
Reponse.Redirect("~/Folder/Page.aspx");
```

Instead of looking in the application folder `(site1/Folder/Page.aspx)`, it is looking in the website root for the folder: `http://servername/Folder/Page.aspx` instead of `'http://servername/site1/Folder/Page.aspx`. How do I get the '~' to refer to the Application root, and not the whole website root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do the trick:  Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Folder/Page.aspx")

Comment: It looks like `Request.ApplicationPath` is the solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.